# Forcing JQuery Datatable to load data via AJAX upon selection of a date range

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, datatables

I have the wonderful jquery data tables currently loading data using ajax.
The code is pretty much the same as the example I took it from which can be found at: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

I found this the best example because it incoporates pagination, sorting and also the search box into the ajax requests. The search box allows you to type in key words and this triggers the ajax function which includes the search value as a $_GET var to the server script.

This is a small preview of my table with table tools etc. loaded.
http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9778/previewxjh.png

As you can see the main focus here is the filament groups date range plugin which I have added. I have finished with this now, and have a fail safe for the duplicate event firing problem etc. its ready to go and just needs including in the ajax pipeline - which is where I have been stuck for the last day or so.

fnDataTablesPipeline appears to be just an interim and doesnt reference the search box at all, so I can't figure out how the search box is working, and I am unsure if this is the right place to go including my date range value (everything I have tried just leads me to a dead end)

I want to use my onChange event for the date range filter, and apply it exactly the same way that the search box works. When the value is changed, simply pass it as a get variable so that my php script can deal with it there. I have concerns regarding the paging, and I will probably need to just reset back to page one after the date is changed (not sure how I am going to deal with this just yet, but thats the next step)

**I need help telling datatables to refresh from the ajax source, and include the date range as a get parameter to the server side script (like when the search box value changes)
- sounds straight forward, but this is where I am breaking down and not making good use of my time due to the lack of understanding.**

Is there anyone that has implemented similar that can help me?

The biggest problem right now is how to force the refresh from my date range onChange event, and of course include the single string value which contains my dates (which I know how to cover server side)

Many Thanks,
Chris

**EDIT: I actually managed to get this working before I finished for the day. I'll post my code when I get back in the office tomorrow, it was actually surprisingly easy - I was tackling it completely wrong.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing date..

```
oTable.fnClearTable(0);
oTable.fnDraw();
```

Include var in pipeline

```
function fnDataTablesPipeline ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, dateRange ) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "dateRange", "value": $('#dateRangePicker').val(), } );
...
```

Obtain var in php script

```
$_GET['dateRange']
```